# Sql query to return list of confirmed customer email, customer name

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql

Please help me with the mysql query to display list of all confirmed customer from my magento db

Answer (score 1):

Below collection will give you all list of confirmed customer collection

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
                ->addNameToSelect()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('confirmation', array('null' => true));

echo $collection->getSelect();
```

Query will be like

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_prefix`.`value` AS `prefix`, `at_firstname`.`value` AS `firstname`, `at_middlename`.`value` AS `middlename`, `at_lastname`.`value` AS `lastname`, `at_suffix`.`value` AS `suffix`, CONCAT(IF(at_prefix.value IS NOT NULL AND at_prefix.value != '', CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(at_prefix.value)), ' '), ''), LTRIM(RTRIM(at_firstname.value)), ' ', IF(at_middlename.value IS NOT NULL AND at_middlename.value != '', CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(at_middlename.value)), ' '), ''), LTRIM(RTRIM(at_lastname.value)), IF(at_suffix.value IS NOT NULL AND at_suffix.value != '', CONCAT(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(at_suffix.value))), '')) AS `name`, `at_confirmation`.`value` AS `confirmation` FROM `customer_entity` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_prefix` ON (`at_prefix`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_prefix`.`attribute_id` = '826') LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_firstname` ON (`at_firstname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_firstname`.`attribute_id` = '1') LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_middlename` ON (`at_middlename`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_middlename`.`attribute_id` = '827') LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_lastname` ON (`at_lastname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_lastname`.`attribute_id` = '2') LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_suffix` ON (`at_suffix`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_suffix`.`attribute_id` = '828') INNER JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_confirmation` ON (`at_confirmation`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_confirmation`.`attribute_id` = '831') WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') AND (at_confirmation.value IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get list ***customer email, customer name*** then you need to join multiple  customer eav table's

- `customer_entity_datetime`
- `customer_entity_decimal`
- `customer_entity_int`
- `customer_entity_text`
- `customer_entity_varchar`

with ***customer_entity***

First you need to get `firstname,last name attribute id` from  **eav_attribute**

> ```
> SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code in ('firstname','lastname','confirmation') 
> and entity_type_id=(SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type 
> WHERE entity_type_code ='customer')
> ```

[image]

After getting attribute_id for *`firstname, last name,confirm`*,you need to mysql quires to getting data.

for your case you need to join  with ***customer_entity_varchar*** as `firstname,lastname,confirmation attribute table`.

### Query

```
SELECT firstnameTable.value as firstname,lastnameTable.value as lastname,main.email as email FROM `customer_entity` as main

LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar as firstnameTable  ON (main.entity_id = firstnameTable.entity_id) AND (firstnameTable.attribute_id = '5') 

LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar as lastnameTable  ON (main.entity_id = lastnameTable.entity_id) AND (lastnameTable.attribute_id = '7')

INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar as confTable where  ON (main.entity_id = confTable.entity_id) AND (confTable.attribute_id = '16') 
where (main.entity_id = '1') AND (confTable.value IS 1)
```

**Note that:** basic of first query the *firstname attribute id is 5*,*lastname attribute_id is 7* and `confirmation attribute id is 16`

[image]

**Also,  sub join and condition is need to add whenever  **  `admin>configuration>Customer>Customer Configuration >Require Emails Confirmation`
 is yes**

```
INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar as confTable where  ON (main.entity_id = confTable.entity_id) AND (confTable.attribute_id = '16') 

and (confTable.value IS 1)
```

If  i want to get from magento resource collection model  then use https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/88715/4564  answer.Just  use `__toString()` for getting query

```
echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to pull the list of customers is from the "sales_flat_order" table. I found that this is the easiest way to get the list of customers with their information especially if you need to import that into Constant Contact or any email marketing solution. This gets you the job done. It includes first name, last name, and email, along with other information such as address.

```
SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE 1
```